# UISlider moving UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using a UIslider to move a UIImage left and right on the screen. When the UISlider is totally on the left the image will be to a certain position on the X atis on the left of the screen, and when the slider is totally to the right, the image is on the right of the screen. If for example I want to give the image flexibility movement of 600px, how can I do that?

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{

if (sender.value >= 0.5) {

int value;
value = sender.value * 6;

[photoView setFrame:CGRectMake(photoView.frame.origin.x + value,
                                PhotoView.frame.origin.y,photoView.frame.size.width,photoView.frame.size.height)];
}else{

int value;
value = sender.value * -6;

[photoView setFrame:CGRectMake(photoView.frame.origin.x + value,
                               photoView.frame.origin.y,photoView.frame.size.width,photoView.frame.size.height)];

}
```

...this was my guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this,

```
slider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
slider.maximumValue = 600.0f;

-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
  [photoView setFrame:CGRectMake(sender.value, PhotoView.frame.origin.y,photoView.frame.size.width,photoView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

You can also do this by changing `photoView.frame.origin.x + value` to `floatValue + value` where `floatValue` is some fixed number based on where you want to set the photoView. Also calculate value as `value = sender.value * constant` where `constant` again depends on how much you need to move it for each slider movement.

Check [documentation for more details on properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do the same thing you're trying to do for use in a full scale aircraft where the iPad/iPhone acts as a instrument gauge.

Here is the code I used to move an image for the aircraft's instrument readout: Also, you should round the float value to an int because we are dealing with whole pixel points. (The image will still move fine with a float value, but I like using an int when dealing with pixel points.)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <math.h>

@interface ViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *XAxis;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISlider *XSlider;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.XSlider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.XSlider.maximumValue = 600.0f;
}

- (IBAction)XValueChanged:(UISlider *)XSlider;
{
    int XResult = (int)floorf(XSlider.value);

    self.XAxis.center = CGPointMake(self.XAxis.center.x, XResult);

    NSLog(@"X Value: %d", XResult);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't really understand what is going on with this: (int)floorf

Comment: your answer was great but I didn't check it as accepted because since I need to do the same thing for width and height, it was better to user the other model, but 1 up!

Comment: (int)floorf rounds the float value from the UISlider down to the nearest integer. When dealing with the pixel points, there is no need to use float because the UIImage can't be in between pixels.